# Why can't I name a project "Con" in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

In Visual Studio I started making a new project named "Config", and I noticed some red text show up after a few letters.

[image: Image showing Visual Studio's new project dialog. "Project name" and "Solution name" contain the text "Con", and under each, there is a warning saying they are empty or invalid]

Why? Is `Con` a reserved word somewhere? It looks like I can make projects named `int` or `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Con` is a reserved keyword for Windows. Try to create a `con` folder or file, and Windows will refuse it

See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-cant-i-create-a-folder-with-con-name/23c86662-4988-4c7d-9c2d-3e33d4413de3